# Perl Dancer Session Cookies

Tags: perl, session, cookies, strawberry-perl, dancer

I am just starting out with Dancer::Session::Cookie, and I have run into some behavior that I am not expecting.  I put together a simple Perl Dancer app to authenticate using Authen::Simple::ActiveDirectory.  My routes are below.

```
package auth;
use Dancer ':syntax';

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
    template 'index', {user => session->{user}};
};

hook 'before' => sub {
    if (! session('user') && request->path_info !~ m{^/login}) {
        var requested_path => request->path_info;
        request->path_info('/login');
    }
};

get '/login' => sub {
    # Display a login page; the original URL they requested is available as
    # vars->{requested_path}, so could be put in a hidden field in the form
    template 'login', { path => vars->{requested_path} };
};

post '/login' => sub {
    # Validate the username and password they supplied
    my $ad = Authen::Simple::ActiveDirectory->new( 
        host      => 'host',
        principal => 'example.com'
    );

    if ($ad->authenticate( params->{user}, params->{pass} )) {
        session user => params->{user};
        redirect params->{path} || '/';
    } else {
        redirect '/login?failed=1';
    }
};

get '/logout' => sub {
    session->destroy;
    redirect '/';
};

true;
```

I am able to successfully log in and create a session.  My username is placed on the main page after login, and I have a link to the /logout route.  When I click on that link, the route is executed (I confirmed this in the debugger), but I am returned to the main page with my username still displayed.  I would expect to be returned to the login page since no session exists.  Any ideas why Dancer is behaving this way?  Have I misunderstood how sessions work?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used Dancer::Session::Cookie before, but it looks like the `destroy` method isn't right - it's just deleting the cookie entry from the parsed hash on the server end, but that doesn't ever get communicated back to the browser.

In place of the call to `session->destroy` try this:

```
cookie session->session_name => '', expires => '-1 day';
```

That's the belt-and-suspenders approach - it empties the cookie and sets the expiration time to occur in the past.